# Writing text above \cdots

Tags: math-mode

My question is: How can I write an index above a set of dots? I mean

```
\mathbb{R} \cdots^{HERE} \mathbb{R}
```

just to say that I have "n" times cartesian product of R.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 13):

Let's make a more realistic example: you want to put *n* above the dots to denote an omission of terms. Here are possible codes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[ X_{1}\times \stackrel{n}{\cdots} \times X_{n} \]

\[ X_{1}\times \overset{n}{\cdots} \times X_{n} \]

\[ X_{1}\times \cdots \times X_{n} \]
\end{document}
```

The last is just for comparison. Here's the result:

[image]

As it's immediately seen, the first has all the spacing wrong because, by rule, TeX transforms the binary operation symbols `\times` into ordinary symbols since they aren't between "legal" operands. This doesn't happen with `\overset` and, in fact, the spacings are correct if we compare the second and third lines.

If the "superscripted `\cdots` doesn't appear between binary operators, it might be necessary to help TeX in adding the correct spacings and

```
\mathinner{\overset{n}{\cdots}}
```

would be the right incantation.

### Final version

Taking into account all of the above, I believe that the best is to define a new command:

```
\newcommand{\scdots}[2][]{\mathinner{#1\overset{#2}{\cdots}#1}}
```

where an optional argument is reserved for additional spacing in case it's needed (I think to overlong superscripts); so

```
\scdots{n}

\scdots{\textup{HERE}}
```

or, maybe,

```
\scdots[\,]{\textup{HERE}}
```

if the superscript really clashes with the adjacent terms.

Answer (score 6):

```
\[ a \stackrel{\scriptstyle\mathrm{HERE}}{\cdots}  b\]
```

[image]

An alternative if you use `amsmath` and want to make egreg happy would be `\overset`

```
\[ a \overset{\mathrm{HERE}}{\cdots}  b\]
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't `\overset` be better?

Answer (score 6):

If you place the `n` index above the dots, there may actually be some ambiguity as to whether the Cartesian product contains `n` or `n+2` elements (since the qualifier may be perceived not to include the first and last element). To avoid any such ambiguity, you could use the `\overbrace` command to generate the following expression:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\begin{document}
\[ \overbrace{\R\times\cdots\times\R}^{\text{$n$ times}} \]
\end{document}
```